# オブジェクトで構成された配列内容をまとめてMySQLへ格納したい

Tags: javascript

```
  var hoge = [
    {a: 3.6, b: 9.7},
    {a: 5.6, b: 3.7},
    {a: 3.5, b: 1.7}
  ];
```

**上記コードで、hoge配列内容全てをMySQLの1カラムへ格納したいのですが、下記のような感じで良いでしょうか？**
・「オブジェクトを格納した配列」を連結した文字列？

```
str = hoge.join(',');
console.log(str); //[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

---

※MySQLへ格納したデータは、別途PHPで取得して編集する予定です

Comment: 上記のコードで試した結果、駄目だったのでしょうか？

Comment: まだ途中なのですが、コンソールログで確認したら、[object Object]としか表示されなかったので(そこから内容を展開できなかったため)、この方法ではダメなのかなと思い質問した

Answer (score 1, accepted):

格納用にカンマに区切っているのであれば、JSON形式で保存する方が扱いやすいと思います。

■javascript

```
var hoge = [
    {a: 3.6, b: 9.7},
    {a: 5.6, b: 3.7},
    {a: 3.5, b: 1.7}
  ];
var hoge_json = JSON.stringify(hoge);
```

■PHP

```
$json_data = json_decode($_REQUEST['hoge_json']);
↑
array(
    0 => array("a" => "3.6", "b" => "9.7"),
    1 => array("a" => "5.6", "b" => "3.7"),
    2 => array("a" => "3.5", "b" => "1.7")
)
```